# GeoDjango application using SpatiaLite database

Tags: python, spatialite, spatial-database, geodjango, django

I want to create a simple GeoDjango app with SpatiaLite database but I have this error at migrate:

> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Unable to load the
>   SpatiaLite library extensio`.

Here the code :

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ..................
    'django.contrib.gis',
     .............
]

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'basetest.sqlite3'),
    }
}
```

Where I went wrong?

Comment: There is some discussion of this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39787700/unable-to-locate-the-spatialite-library-django

Answer (score 2):

You need to install the SQLite spatial extension SpatiaLite:

- on Debian-based GNU/Linux distributions (es: Debian, Ubuntu, …):

  ```
   $ apt install libsqlite3-mod-spatialite
  ```
- on macOS using Hoembrew:

  ```
    $ brew install spatialite-tools
  ```

You can find complete example of a map with Geodjango and Spatialite in this article:
[Maps with Django (part 1): GeoDjango, SpatiaLite and Leaflet](https://www.paulox.net/2020/12/08/maps-with-django-part-1-geodjango-spatialite-and-leaflet/)

Answer (score 0):

In manjaro system/Arch, the install command is:

```bash
sudo pacman -Sy libspatialite
```